# How can we remove java.lang.AssertionError from failure message in TestNG

Tags: unit-testing, selenium, testing, automation, testng

After `Assert.fail("some message");` in TestNG, the failure message I am getting is like:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: some message
    at org.testng.test.BasicTest.test(BasicTest.java:11)
... Removed 31 stack frames
```

But I want failure message only, like :

```
some message
```

That means, I want to remove stack trace info:

```
java.lang.AssertionError:
```

and

```
at org.testng.test.BasicTest.test(BasicTest.java:11)
    ... Removed 31 stack frames
```

Here, I wrote listener to get control over method execution, changed failure message:

```
public class ErrorMessageListener implements IInvokedMethodListener {
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ErrorMessageListener.class);
    @Override
    public void beforeInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult testResult) {}
    @Override
    public void afterInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult result) {
        logger.info("Invoked afterInvocation(IInvokedMethod, ITestResult)");
        if (method.isTestMethod() && ITestResult.FAILURE == result.getStatus()) {
            Throwable throwable = result.getThrowable();
            String originalMessage = throwable.getMessage();
            logger.info("Original : " + originalMessage);
            String modifiedMessage = originalMessage.replace("java.lang.AssertionError:", "").trim();
            logger.info("Modified : " + modifiedMessage);
            try {
                FieldUtils.writeField(throwable, "detailMessage", modifiedMessage, false);
            } catch (Exception cause) {
                cause.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and added it to test class :

```
@Listeners(ErrorMessageListener.class)
public class BasicTest {
    @Test
    public void test(){
         Assert.fail("some message");
     }
}
```

But still I am getting same failure message :

```
java.lang.AssertionError: some message
        at org.testng.test.BasicTest.test(BasicTest.java:11)
    ... Removed 31 stack frames
```

Answer (score 0):

`ITestListener#onTestFailure` that is what you need.

There you will get `ITestResult` instance with `getThrowable()` and `setThrowable()` - you can modify them in any way your like.

Answer (score -1):

You may want to consider using an if statement to test your condition. If it turns out to be false, simply print out your message

```
if("your condition"){

}else{
    System.out.println("some message");
    throw "applicable exception";
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But it is not about just printing the message, Assert.fail fails the test case and I have captured the failure messages in report.